# How to create a video cutter in C# which continue play movie while watching similar this one

Tags: c#, video, video-processing

Can any one suggest me How to create a video cutter in C# which continue play movie while watching similar this one:
[http://agalaxycode.blogspot.com/2016/02/video-cutter.html](http://agalaxycode.blogspot.in/2016/02/video-cutter.html)

While cutting a movie part I don't want to face any error message like file sharing, file already in used error etc.

I want to create similar video cutter. The most important things is that his video cutter cut the movie part while movie is running. It is amazing things. can someone give me idea how can I achieve it?

Comment: I have already found some code but it is showing file already in used error.

Comment: You might have to add some picture grab or even put a demo usage clip on youtube link cos otherwise no one knows what you mean. Who will download & extract **17 .rar** files just to answer this question?

Comment: Anyways to "edit" while it plays usually means editing **a copy** (ram? temp file? etc options) of the video and then "sampling" from it those required frames (or bytes). If you find you can open/use original video file in another program whilst his is editing then it's definately editing some temporary copy.

Comment: No, It is not copying file in ram or creating temp file. I have open 1.30 Gbs file in that video cutter and play it. while playing set the from and start position and cut the part. It was cutting and I was seeing video of next section.

Comment: if any one want to use this types of software then he/she will download 17.rar file.  It is no matter how many files,  what 17.rar files, if it will 70.rar files then also peoples download it.

Comment: Anybody can help me?